# If hosting only one site on a server with no control panel, is there any advantage to using a virtual host?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, virtualhost

The site is hosted on AWS and the website is dropped into the var www html directory. Is there any advantage to setting up a virtual host considering this will be the only domain on the server?

Comment: Are you talking about apache? If so you should use the "apache" tag. I would expect it would provide flexibility, say if you want to add a test site or subdomain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of placing your web site in a virtual host is that the default (virtual) host, which Apache's syntax doesn't place inside any `<VirtualHost>` block, will catch requests for any site *other* than yours. This includes things like `localhost` (if you didn't make a virtual host for it), the system's IP address, no host specified, etc. Nearly all of such traffic is garbage or potentially malicious, and by default they get a 403, 404 and/or a tiny test page (depending on your distribution), and never hit your web application.

These days, with most web sites moving to HTTPS, it's also a good idea to enable the default HTTPS virtual host (which the default Apache config usually has commented out) with a self-signed certificate such as the snakeoil.crt that Debian systems create. This will prevent such garbage or malicious HTTPS traffic as described above from reaching your web app.